# popup Message Dialog with a TextBox in universal apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to create a popup Message Dialog with a TextBox,that will send the input text to a variable,I didn't found good solutions in the net for the universal apps
any help please and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use a ContentDialog or a Flyout with a TextBox as content. Then you only have to bind a variable to the TextBox's Text attribute. A bind can be done with

```
Text={x:Bind VariableName, Mode=TwoWay}
```

See the following links for further details:

- [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx)
- [Flyout class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.ASPx)
- [ContentDialog class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) instead. [Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/ContentDialogExample.xaml) from Microsoft on github.

`MessageDialog` is for simple messages only.